# Fixed menu gets under WOW Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I got a issue with my WOW slider where the menu gets under it instead of over it when scrolling down.

What can I do to fix this? I seem to tried to apply z-index: 100 and even 99999 to menu/nav bar and it still goes under it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmfU4.png

```
<div class="navigation stick">
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="nav">
                <li><a href="#frontpage">Frontpage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutme">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div id="textcontainer">
                <div id="textbox">
                    Here is a overview of my current and previous projects. Click on the picture to get more information.
                </div>
                <div id="slider_container">
                    <div id="wowslider-container1">
                        <div class="ws_images">
                            <ul>
                                <li><img src="img/projects/c17_big.jpg" title="City 17"/>A roleplay gamemode for testing.</li>
                                <li><img src="img/projects/heartbit_big.jpg" title="HeartBit Roleplay"/>HeartBit Roleplay</li>
                                <li><img src="img/projects/tb_big.jpg" title="TigerBit"/>TigerBit</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="ws_bullets">
                            <div>
                            <a href="#">1</a>
                            <a href="#">2</a>
                            <a href="#">3</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="slider_engine/wowslider.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="slider_engine/script.js"></script>

            </div>
```

And the CSS of the codes:

```
.nav{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;


    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.nav li{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1420px;
    float: none;
}

.nav li a{
    color: white;
}

.nav li a:hover{
    height: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: orange;
}

#slider_container{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you add a position to the bav bar before using z-index?

Comment: Added the code so you can see yourself.

Comment: Add `position: relative;` to your `#slider_container` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you try：

```
.navigation{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#textcontainer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

If your project online, I can see what the problem is, if you convenient, can the code into the [codepen .io](http://codepen.io/)

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work out. You can check out the code here: http://tigerbit.com/test/

Answer (score 1):

Easy , go to animate.css

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Remove the animation-full-mode then change z-index to -999

```
#slider_container{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    z-index: -999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will add the position and z-index fo their parents. if the menu is in header and the wow slider in the content, you can do like this:

```
.header {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
}
.content {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. I added my code now if that helps you maybe specify a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

`#slidecontainer` needs a position to make the z-index working.

Answer (score 0):

I have viewed you code, please try it:

```
#undefined-sticky-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#pagewidth {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

please view the screen shoot.[image]

You have multiple identical page id of the div element, it is not good, it is recommended that you modify these.